# Resizing the BITMAP to a lower resolution

Tags: android

I have an issue while trying to reduce the resolution of an image taken with Samsung Tablet. The actual image size is 1932 x 2576 when taken from the custom camera that I created. When I try to change the resolution to 960 x 720, the image stretches. However, if I set the resolution to 720 x 960, the image is fine. Is it not possible to change the width and height without stretching?

I get a bitmap and tried this:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,960,720,true);
```

I also tried this:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) 960) / width;
        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        float scaleHeight = ((float) 720) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false );
        image.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

This is the result I get:

[image: actual image]

This is the result I expect:

[image: expected image]

I have seen posts asking the same question but they all had similar answers that I tried. I also think this is because the camera itself has a resolution with height greater than width, if I try to have width greater than height, will it not work? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid it's not very clear what you're asking. Am I right to understand that you're asking whether you can change the aspect ratio of an image without it being stretched? If that's what you're asking, then the answer is obviously no! I don't understand how you're expecting something different to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same aspect ratio.

`1932 / 2576` is the same aspect ratio like `720 / 960`. That's why your image is fine.

But you want to use `960 / 720` and that's not like `1932 / 2576`.

To calculate the right height use this formula:

```
height = width * 0.75
```

To calculate the right width use this formula:

```
width = height / 0.75
```

`0.75` is because `1932 / 2576 = 0.75`